# Exporting Excel from Laravel without installing any library and getting strange chars

Tags: php, excel, laravel, encode

Using Laravel 8

My route:

`Route::get('socios/export', [SocioController::class, 'export'])->name('socios.export');`

My Controller method:

```
public function export(Request $request)
    {
        $registros = User::socios()->get();
        $content = view('socios.excel', compact('registros'));
        
        $status = 200;
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="filename.xls"',
        ];

        $response = response($content, $status, $headers);
        return $response;
    }
```

My 'socios.excel' view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($registros as $registro)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $registro->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $registro->name }}</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The file exports fine but string like "Dirección" contains wrong chars:

[image]

I had try different charset in content-type header but can not fix it.

Some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard is UTF-8 but MS Excel use default CP/WIN-125X .. Try to convert your content before returning: `$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "Windows-1252",  "UTF-8"); // or 1250 or 1255`, it depends

Comment: In my experience as well I've found that the DB has to be connected with UTF-8 as well. No matter the `mb_convert_encoding` it came down to the database connction

Comment: Laravel's configuration file as mentioned in their [configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#configuration-using-urls)

Comment: $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "Windows-1252",  "UTF-8"); fixes the stuff!! Thanks!!